# sonarqueue plugin for java ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

We are using sonarqube quite alot for our code analysis, but we do get false errors as sonar does not recognize the ejb annotations for methods:

```
@PostConstruct
protected void initialize() {
    service = getService();
}
```

this gives unused protected method, it could very well have been private too, it is only protected for testing purpose.
So my question is how do I avoid getting Java EE annotations or other annotations to give errors in sonar?

And no we do not want to use //NOSONAR

We would like for sonar to know that this method would be called by the container, even though there is no code calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, feel free to vote for https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-117 which should be fixed in version 2.5 of the SonarQube Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Freddy's bug was replaced by this one: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1179 but it is still open.

If you do not want to use // NOSONAR which turns off all warnings, you can use this annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:UnusedProtectedMethod")
```

You can also switch off the issue in Sonar GUI.

See more info here http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-NOSONAR